# Horizontally align images in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align these images horizontally but it just won't work. I have tried floating them and using inline-block CSS but I think I'm just missing something simple.

```
<div class="footer-bottom"> 
    <div class="footer-container">

       Gold Sponsors<br />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"><br />
       Silver Sponsors<br />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"><br />

    </div>
</div>

<style>
   .footer-container {
       width: 120px;
       height: 72px;
       display: inline-block;
   }

   /* resize images */
   .footer-container img {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
   }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want to do, so I'm going to provide two answers.

1) If you want to distribute your pictures horizontally, you need two things. First, make `footer-bottom` bigger. Right now, it's too small to fit more than one picture. I changed the width of this container to `auto`, to fit the width of the screen.

```css
.footer-bottom {
  width: auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* resize images */
.footer-container img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-bottom"> 
    <div class="footer-container">

       Gold Sponsors<br />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"><br />
       Silver Sponsors<br />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"><br />

    </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to horizontally align your pictures, like centering them, just set `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `.footer-container` to `auto`.

```css
.footer-container {
   width: 120px;
   height: 72px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

 /* resize images */
.footer-container img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-bottom"> 
    <div class="footer-container">

       Gold Sponsors<br />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"><br />
       Silver Sponsors<br />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100"><br />

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
.footer-container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 72px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/3fb6msvm/

Comment: Wow I didn't realize that was so easy. Thanks for your help!